# If $a, b \in G$ are such that $a^4=e$ and $a^2*b=b*a$ show that $a=e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ be a group. If $a, b \in G$ are such that $a^4=e$ and $a^2*b=b*a$ show that $a=e$.

$a^2*b=b*a \implies ab=a^{-1}*b*a$.
I can't proceed further.

Answer (score 9):

You just have to combine your two equations!

If $a^4 = e$ and $a^2b = ba$, then
$$
b = a^4b = a^2(a^2b) = a^2(ba) = (a^2b)a = (ba)a = ba^2
$$
and therefore $a^2 = e$. But if $a^2 = e$, then $b = a^2b = ba$, so $a=e$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 5):

$$a^2b=ba \tag{*}$$Left-multiply both sides of $(*)$ by $b^{-1}$
$$ a = b^{-1}a^2 b$$
Square both side to get $$a^2 = b^{-1}a^4b = e$$
Plug this into $(*)$ to get $$\begin{align} ba &= a^2b \\ &= eb \\ &=b \end{align}$$
Hence, we have $ba = b$ which gives $a=e$.

Comment: In spirit we have the same proof, but yours is more group-oriented and hints at your experience with computing in the presentation of dihedral groups. Mine works in a cancellative monoid because I didn't use inverses, and in those kinds of questions sometimes the assumption that $G$ is a group is relaxed. I like both for different reasons :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes, you are right. But whenever I see *"Let ... be a group"*, I feel the power of having an inverse element :D

Answer (score -1):

Proof:
As a⁴=e. Then
b=a⁴b
b=(a²)²b
since a²*b=b*a
b=ba²
Since G is a group
b=a²b
Since
a²*b=b*a
b=ba=>a=e.